# How can I simplify this repetitive jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

This code lets me display/hide a custom message `msg_one` `msg_two` `msg_three` when the appropriate div is hovered/unhovered over. The appropriate message is injected into the `#screen div` and show/hide is then applied. The code is almost identical except for the first 2 lines `#one vs #two vs #three` and the message being displayed `msg_one msg_two msg_three`.

How can I simplify this into fewer lines of code to get rid of the repetitiveness?

```
var msg_one = "message 1";
var msg_two = "message 2";
var msg_three = "message 3";

$("#one").hover(function()  { 
    $("#screen").html(msg_one).show(); 
}, function(){ 
    $("#screen").html("").hide(); 
});

$("#two").hover(function()  { 
    $("#screen").html(msg_two).show(); 
}, function(){ 
    $("#screen").html("").hide(); 
});

$("#three").hover(function() { 
    $("#screen").html(msg_three).show(); 
}, function(){ 
    $("#screen").html("").hide(); 
});
```

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extend jQuery, like this:

```
$.fn.hover_message = function (message) {
    $(this).bind("hover", function()    { 
        $("#screen").html(message).show(); 
    }, function(){ 
        $("#screen").html("").hide(); 
    });
}
```

And use the function, like this:

```
$("#one").hover_message(msg_one);
$("#two").hover_message(msg_two);
$("#three").hover_message(msg_three);
```

Comment: pretty neat, I'll try it out.

Comment: Definitely the way to go here. Extending jQuery = productivity

Comment: @J-P, What is caching #screen? How to do it?

Comment: To me, caching #screen is premature optimization. But you would do it by adding a var $screen = $("#screen") before the bind, and then use that instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can put each of the three messages in a `title` attribute of the corresponding `<div>`. Then you can add a class to the divs and:

```
$('.hover-div').hover(function()  { 
    var msg = $(this).attr('title');
    $("#screen").html(msg).show(); 
}, function(){ 
    $("#screen").html("").hide(); 
});
```

I hope the code works, I wrote it out of my head :). Anyway, the idea is ok.

Answer (score 2):

```
var msgs = {
    'one': 'message 1',
    'two': 'message 2',
    'three': 'message 3'
}
$('#one, #two, #three').hover(function(){
    $("#screen").html(msgs[this.id]).show(); 
}, function () {
    $("#screen").html("").hide(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If "#one", "#two", and "#three" are all in the same container, you could take advantage of that:

```
$("#container").hover(function(e) {
    $("#screen").html($(e.target).attr("title")).show();
}, function(e) {
    $("#screen").html("").hide();
})
```

Comment: This isn't ok. The container may be larger and may contain more than just the three divs.

Comment: That's true. It depends on his situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
[{elem: '#one', msg: msg_one },
 {elem: '#two', msg: msg_two },
 {elem: '#three', msg: msg_three }
].each(function(item) {
    $(item.elem).hover(function() {
        $("#screen").html(item.msg).show();
    },
    function() {
        $("#screen").html("").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a simple plugin which you can reuse in the long run:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){

    $.fn.hoverScreen = function(options){
        var config = $.extend({}, $.fn.hoverScreen.defaults, options);
        return this.each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.hover(function(){
                config.screenElem.html(config.text).show();             
            }, function(){
                config.screenElem.html('').hide();
            });
        });
    }

    $.fn.hoverScreen.defaults = {
        screenElem: null,
        text: ''
    }

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Usage would be now really simple:

```
$(function(){
    $.fn.hoverScreen.defaults.screenElem = $("#screen");
    $("#one").hoverScreen({ text: 'message one' });
    $("#two").hoverScreen({ text: 'message two' });
});
```